# split text based on the back arrow symbol in the text

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting the below text from an API call with some specific symbol as shown in the "circle" in the below image.
I need to split the text based on this symbol ( back arrow symbol).
Can someone let me know, what this symbol is?

[image: Text to be splitted]

> posting row text as requested:

```
“The endpoint is browser-based, rather than RESTful. Therefore it could 
 result in the following different scenarios,↵1. SUCCESS 
(response_type=code)↵> redirect_uri?code=<authorization-code>&scope= 
<resource-owner-approved-scopes>[&state=<state-provided-by-the-client>]↵2. 
SUCCESS (response_type=token)↵> redirect_uri#token=<access-token>?scope= 
<resource-owner-approved-scopes>[&state=<state-provided-by-the-client>]↵3. 
CLIENT_ERROR↵> redirect_uri?error=<standard-error>&error_description= 
<description-of-the-error>↵4. FAILURE↵> Resource Owner will be alerted with 
an error page and the OAuth2 flow terminates immediately."
```

Comment: @CodeManiac just added the raw text

Comment: please post the code you've tried so far as well as desired output, which will help you to get exact answer, instead of wild guesses, `split('↵')` seems to do the job isn't it ?

Comment: Are you sure those arrows are in the original text, and not a transformation to display the text. I ask this because `↵` is used to represent a newline.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent(yourString)` and figure out what they are

Comment: @Musa I just checked again and I think, I completely got confused with that new line symbol to some type of unknown symbol. As I am processing the string and not directly displaying it  in a html element. Thank you pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That arrow generally means a 'return' or newline. It's where line breaks are manually entered into the text. If you render this into HTML, it should show with the line breaks. If you want to split the string based on them, you can use regex: `str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)`

Comment: You are right. let me test this quickly and I will accept it. Thank You.

Comment: can you help me with the regex to find the ↵> character in the string. as I need to add some css when I see these two character together. And I need to add some other css when I JUST see the newline character ↵ alone ( without greater-than sign).

Comment: actually can you modified your earlier regex(/\r\n|\r|\n/) to include the > character? I tried , like (\r\n>|\n>|\r>) , but it is not working for me.

Comment: I am pretty bad with regex.

Comment: That's why I love regex101.com. Easy testing and explanations of whats going on. If you want a version similar to the regex above but with the `>`, you could do ``(\r\n|\r|\n|↵)>` https://regex101.com/r/XueUhQ/2

Comment: Thanks for all the help.